# Symfony2 : Replace parameters.php for PAAS (Heroku)

Tags: symfony, heroku, paas

I use Symfony2 App. I would like to replace parameters.php auto-generated by parameters.heroku.php to have environment variables. This file must be replaced before Symfony2 actions (dumping assets, database update, etc).

What are best practices please ?

I tried to put this action in the composer.json, but this action will launch at each update composing, even outside of Heroku.

My actual composer.json :

```
    {
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/Evolunium/IvoryCKEditorBundle"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.7",
     ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "./composer_script.sh",
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "cp parameters.heroku.php.dist app/config/parameters.php", // Correct ?
      "./composer_script.sh",
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "compile": [
      "rm web/app_dev.php",
      "app/console assetic:dump"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/components",
    "component-baseurl": "/components"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    },
    "config": {
      "bin-dir": "bin",
      "component-dir": "web/components",
      "component-baseurl": "/components"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "~1.0@dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
Johnny